# Table name is specified more than once

Tags: mysql, sql, psql

I am getting the ERROR: "table name 'temp' specified more than once" when trying to perform a join on two tables.
Every example I've look at is set out as mine is so what is wrong?

```
UPDATE info.temp
SET RobberID = info.Robber.RobberID
FROM info.temp
INNER JOIN info.Robber
ON info.temp.NickName = info.Robber.NickName;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of these

```
UPDATE t1
SET RobberID = info.Robber.RobberID
FROM info.temp as t1
INNER JOIN info.Robber as t2
ON t1.NickName = t2.NickName;
```

or

```
UPDATE info.temp
SET RobberID = (select info.Robber.RobberID FROM info.Robber
WHERE info.temp.NickName = info.Robber.NickName)
```

Comment: just matter of seconds .. :)

Comment: Cheers buddy the second one worked first go. How does the AS work in the first one? How are you updating a table I don't have

Comment: so i did vote up for urs so now ur turn.. n question asker ur too

Comment: the alias t1 is referring to the table info.temp

Answer (score 0):

your are updating info.temp by value form info.temp in wrong way
do this way

```
UPDATE info.temp
SET RobberID =  (select info.Robber.RobberID
FROM info.temp
INNER JOIN info.Robber
ON info.temp.NickName = info.Robber.NickName);
```

Comment: You do not need a join. Look at my second method

Comment: o ya sorry sory my mistake